# how to create AdView programmatically without layout.xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob

Hi i've been trying to implement admob ads in this game for a while, i'm always stopped by `mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);` error, the whole game is in java and i have no `layout.xml` file

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);

    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    // Add the adView to it
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
    layout.addView(adView);

    setContentView(layout);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found the answer and you have no idea how stupid i was for not trying it once; the solution was to simply delete this from code" mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView); "

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this -

```
   AdView mAdView = new AdView(activity);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =  new RelativeLayout
        .LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
   mAdView.setLayoutParams(params);
   mAdView.setId(R.id.adView);
   mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
   mAdView.setAdUnitId(activity.getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
   adLayout.removeView(activity.findViewById(R.id.adView));
   adLayout.addView(mAdView);;
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
   mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

For more check this - https://www.concretepage.com/questions/429

Comment: thanks for the answer , the only problem i have is with (R.id.adView) it's always red, i guess the only solution is to add an xml file in layout because i have nowhere to put this
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

Comment: Did you tried my answer? Xml code is not required for this. Please check variable name. Also check link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating everything in code; then what's the need to add this line?

```
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

Remove this and you are good to go.